# Strange fragment lifecycle behavior: onCreate called twice

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've created simple fragment.

**FRAGMENT CLASS**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
static int count = 0;
static TextView tv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("TEST", "oncreate");
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag, container, false);
    tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    return view;
}

public static TextView setMyText(String text) {
    tv.setText(text);
    return tv;
}
}
```

But the thing is that onCreate fragment is called twice (when activity is first launched). Anyone has an idea why? In fact every lifecycle method is called twice ( onAttach, onResume..). I'm **not** rotating screen or anything, if someone might wonder. Is this common case or I'm doing something wrong here?

**ACTIVITY CLASS**

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private static int COUNT = 0;
private static int COUNT2 = 5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vp);
    vp.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    vp.setOnPageChangeListener(new CustomPageListener());       
}


private static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    MyFragment mf = new MyFragment();
    return mf;      
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { 
        return 5;
    }

}

private class CustomPageListener extends ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener {



    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        MyFragment.setMyText("This is page "+position);

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` will instantiate two pages for ViewPager. The onCreate it is called twice, once for each fragment returned by  `public Fragment getItem(int position)`

Comment: Hm this is kinda "annoying" for two main reasons, 1: Lifecycle is messed up. If I swipe between pages only three more times (if there are 5 pages which Adapter returns) onCreate is called. So twice when activity is launched, and then three more times. That means that last two fragments in my viewpager does not receive "onCreate" call. 2: It's annoying to code anything in onCreate since code will be run twice. Is there any work around here or..?

Comment: you can try with pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0). I dont know if it will work